# Laptops trying to connect via wireless? Only able to connect only via wired connection

Tags: networking, wireless-router

It seems that all the wireless laptops in the office have disconnected and are unable to reconnect to the wifi after a terrible storm caused some power interruptions.

**Troubleshooting actions**

- Verify wireless broadcasting is up
- With each laptop i ended up flushing their dns cache on Win 7 (ipconfig /flush )
- Performed an ipconfig /all to see what the new ip is
- Made sure password was correct
- Reset the router (multiple times)
- restarted each laptop. Tried connecting wirelessly

Am i missing some small detail ?

**Network information**

- The router is a linksys/cisco WRVS4400N router. Supports a lot of fancy features i don't know how to use.
- We have 3 static ip's the conference room computer, the wireless printer, my computer
- Mostly windows machines, we have 3 mac users

Comment: Can anyone (on wired) connect to the wireless printer?

Comment: Sniff the router. If it smells of ozone, you might need a new one.

Comment: Can they get on the Internet using the wireless? Just because it says connected, doe not mean it is not fryed.

Comment: Wireless users can connect to the router but not the internet. I'll check on that printing. I guess that's a good diagnostic test.

Answer (score 1):

try resetting the modem. if they can connect with wireless but they can't get out of the intranet. then your router isn't forwarding data